# How can I convert using statement in vb syntax

Tags: c#, vb.net, namespaces

In c# i am using this code:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString))
{
    //code here
}
```

What is the equivalent vb syntax? TIA!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a **code converter** at all. Use some online tools like http://converter.telerik.com/ or http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ These tools gives me this as a result: `Using sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString)
End Using`

Comment: Is Google down at your place? Just google "vb net using block" and you will find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
        Using sqlConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString)

        End Using
```

Comment: Thank you Al-3sli for your answer. I dont know why they keep down voting my post. Ive been working with c# for 3yrs and this is my first vb project.

Comment: @devkiat - I didn't downvote, but you're getting downvoted because if you had typed your question,as is, into Google, you would have seen many hits which explain the VB syntax.  Also, as others have said, SO is not meant for questions regarding code translation.  If you had shown your own attempt to translate the code, then someone would have likely helped you.  You can also look at the VB language spec which is installed with Visual Studio.